# Suppressing a beep winform / textbox

Tags: keydown, beep

I have a key sequence "CTRL+U" and in the form I have a `KeyDown` method that looks at the key variable `e` and does what it wants. It does not set a result.

It works.

But if the focus on the form is in a text box and I press the key combination, it still works, but then I get the beep.

I am a little confused as to how to resolve this as it sounds a lot of work to have to suppress a key event in every control (should I have several text boxes).

The handler:

```
    private void XXXXXForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Control)
        {
            bool bHandle = false;
            bool bChecked = true;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.U)
            {
                bChecked = false;
                bHandle = true;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.T)
            {
                bChecked = true;
                bHandle = true;
            }

            if(bHandle)
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Possibly you can solve this by setting the key to 0, null, #0 or any other similar value in the keydown and keyup events after you process it, but we'd need some details (the language you are using, for one) to help you further.

Comment: Hi. I have just added the code to the original post. Stripped out the "stuff" for simplicity. So that is the windows form key down handler. The language is c#. Sorry I did not mention!

Comment: Can you try setting `e.KeyCode = 0` in this event handler?

Comment: Well, I can use e.Handled = true; But it still beeps.

Comment: I needed: e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this information on another website:

> The "e.Handled = true;" statement is not doing what you think here.
>   The documentation [^]for this is confusing, and one could interpret it
>   the way you have. However, you need to realize that they are talking
>   about setting "Handled" in the KeyPress Event. To make matters worse,
>   the KeyPressed event uses KeyPressEventArgs not KeyEventArgs.
>
> Instead use e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

That was the solution!